# Column formatting in Microsoft Sharepoint

Tags: json, sharepoint

I currently am working on a way to format the colums of my company's Sharepint in a useful way. In my opinion the display of the Picture size is also very important.

I tried to do that via adding or removing the column, but there isn't an option to display picture size. So I tried finding a JSON Code on the Microsoft GitHub page but didn't find a useful Code there either. Unfortunately I am not a Coder, so I am not able to come up with a Code by myself. When I try and search for it online, I only find ways to resize the picture in order for it to be displayed better.

So my question is, if there is any way to display the picture size in a column on the Sharepoint.

Thank you so much!
Shiobhan

Answer (score 0):

There is a `File Size` column in the SharePoint library.

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

**Updated:**

[image]

Comment: Hello!

thank you for the quick response. I don't mean the file size, I meant the pixel size of an image, like 1920px x 1080px for example. I can't seem to put these information on a column

Comment: I did not find width and height in the attributes available for json formatting, but we can read the length and width of the image from the rest API. Check my update.

Comment: You could create a flow to update the width column and height column when the image is uploaded.